# Reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode alongside Manjaro

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, uefi, manjaro, bios

I initially had Manjaro installed in UEFI mode. I then used a Ubuntu live USB to install Ubuntu on a new separate partition. I choose the default options and it seems that it has not installed it in UEFI mode.

To boot into Ubuntu I need to change the bios settings to use the legacy boot order and then back to UEFI when I want to boot into Manjaro.

When I'm in legacy boot mode grub does ask if I want to boot Manjaro but when I choose this option I get 'Operation system not found'.

What would be the best method of rectifying this? Should I start from scratch?

ta!
Gareth

Comment: Yes, you should start from scratch and keep in mind how it boots is how it installs. Suggestion: Disable Legacy/CSM assures you'll be booting in UEFI mode.